# Perform sub-controller call by AJAX

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, controller

I'm creating a Joomla plugin and I've created a custom task (in other words, a new function) and i would like to create a sub-controller file in which to insert it.

The problem is that i'm writing a plugin and i want to add a new custom task without altering `components/com_content/controller.php` file. All this because i do not know how to add my tack-function to `controller.php` during installation of the plugin.

In fact, I have no problems if I simply insert my new function in the above-mentioned `controller.php`

I've tried to write a sub-controller as I've read here:
[With Joomla, how do I get into an AJAX call only the output generated by the php function called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453326/with-joomla-how-do-i-get-into-an-ajax-call-only-the-output-generated-by-the-php)

Scilicet:

1) I've created a new sub-controller file: `/components/com_content/controllers/myTaskController.raw.php`. In this new controller file I have tried to insert only my custom task-function (`myTaskFunction`), after I've created a new class, too. But it doesn't work :(

2) Then I call the custom task using the url `index.php?option=com_content&task=myTaskController.myTaskFunction&format=raw`. But it doesn't work :(

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: why dont you create your own component with its own controller? You should keep your extensions and core files somewhat seperated...

Comment: Because i don't absolutely need of new component, it would just be an additional (and useless) code.
I only need a plugin feature to perform some reg exp on html page.

Yes, I agree with you that the core files and extensions must be separated. In fact, if i create a new and separated controller file in /components/com_content/controllers directory, i keep them quite separated.

Comment: That is not keeping them separated as com_content is a system component so future upgrades could overwrite your files. Take a look at the Component Creator, you can make a new component in minutes: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator